# "walk away" meaning in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

> I'd never taken an accounting course, never run a business, never even had savings of my own to manage. I'd stumbled into a job at Salomon Brothers in 1985, and stumbled out, richer, in 1988, and event though I wrote a book about the experience, the whole thing still strikes me as totally preposterous—which is one reason the money was so easy to **walk away from**.—*The Big Short* by Michael Lewis—

Hello, I wondered the meaning of part "walk away from" while reading this phrase.
I assume money walking away from him after he got richer but I wonder what reason made money walk away here, is it his lack of his money managing skill or thing that was preposterous?

Also I searched a meaning "walk away" in a Lexico Dictionary and I don't get how casually or irresponsibly if money would withdraw.

> **Casually or irresponsibly** withdraw from a situation in which one is involved or for which one is responsible.(Lexico Dictionary)

Comment: The narrator is walking away from the money.

Comment: "walk away" = to leave something behind. To no longer have it in your life.

Comment: [A better definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/walk-away):  to leave a place, situation, or person

Comment: Oh, "he" is walking away. I thought money was easy to walk away from him.

Comment: "Money" must be the object of "from", so your interpretation isn't possible. There's no structure in English like "Money is easy to walk away". It makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/walk%20away%20from) says:

> to cause to remain behind

> synonyms: abandon

In this case, the narrator is abandoning the money.

The phrase is common when you elect to forgo an opportunity.